# I need check if enum element is into enum set

Tags: java, enums

I'm new in java. I need check if enum element is into enum set.

in Delphi:

```
type
  TWeekEnum = (weMonday, weTuesday, weWednesday, weThursday, weFriday, weSaturday, weSunday)
  TWeekSetEnum = (weSaturday, weSunday)


  if (weSunday in (TWeekSetEnum))
  ...
```

Java?

Comment: `if(TWeekSetEnum.contains(weSunday))`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Comment: This is not a code conversion website. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Beware: enums in Java are strongly typed. Your question therefore doesn't have an "exact" answer.

Comment: @fge, true, but creating subsets is pretty easy.

Answer (score 18):

You can define the `enum` this way, and then also create your subsets as static methods on it.

```
public enum TWeekEnum {
    weMonday, weTuesday, weWednesday, weThursday, weFriday, weSaturday, weSunday;

    public static EnumSet<TWeekEnum> getWeekend() {
        return EnumSet.of(weSaturday, weSunday);
    }

    public static EnumSet<TWeekEnum> getWeekDays() {
        return EnumSet.complementOf(getWeekend());
    }
}
```

Then you can check if it contains your selected item like this

```
TWeekEnum.getWeekend().contains(TWeekEnum.weTuesday)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the elements to be in the *calling code* (and not inside the enum) - another solution is to add a normal method named `in` as follows: -

```java
public enum TWeekEnum {
    weMonday, weTuesday, weWednesday, weThursday, weFriday, weSaturday, weSunday;

    public boolean in (TWeekEnum ... weekEnum) {
        return Arrays.asList(types).contains(this);
    }

}
```

This can be called anywhere in the codebase as follows: -

```java
TWeekEnum weekEnum = TWeekEnum.weSaturday;      // <---- If set dynamically, check for null
if (weekEnum.in(TWeekEnum.weSaturday, TWeekEnum.weSunday)) {
    // do something
}
```

... this can look nicer (and read better) if enum values statically imported i.e.

```java
import static com.foo.TWeekEnum.weSaturday;
import static com.foo.TWeekEnum.weSunday;

...

if (weekEnum.in(weSaturday, weSunday)) {
    // do something
}
```